# XPATH If exists then else - infinite loop

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape/parse a book using XPATH and scrapy. It's in HTML file format (local).

A typical page consists of some text content and usually (but not always) some footnotes. I want the main text only while ignoring the footnotes. It's okay if the XPath catches the superscript footnote marker <sup>(like this one)</sup>, but the footnotes MUST be totally ignored.

```
<html>
<div class="page" id="pg446"><div class="pgcontent">
    <p class="rfdNormal0">Bunch of Text<span class="rfdFootnotenum"> (1) </span>Some Nested Text<span class="rfdFootnotenum"> (2) </span>Bunch of Text</p>
<p>Bunch of Text</p>
<p>Bunch of Text</p>
<p class="rfdLine">__________________</p>
<p class="rfdFootnote0">(1)
Footnote 1</p>
<p class="rfdFootnote0">(2)
Footnote 2</p>
</div>
<div class="pgnum">--page 446--</div></div>
</div><div class="page" id="pg447"><div class="pgcontent">
    <p class="rfdNormal0">Bunch of Text</p>
<p>Bunch of text</p>
<p>Some Text here <span class="rfdAlaem">(</span><span class="rfdAie">Nested Text</span><span class="rfdAlaem">)</span> Bunch of Text</p>
</div>
<div class="pgnum">--page 447--</div>
</div>
</html>
```

The footnotes start after this tag:

```
<p class="rfdLine">__________________</p>
```

Thus everything before this tag is to be caught; and everything after it is to be ignored on each page. However, not all pages have footnotes, some don't, like page 447.

I tried the following XPATH expression:

```
//div[@class="pgcontent"]//*[contains(@*, "rfdLine")]/preceding-sibling::*|//div[@class="pgcontent" and count(.//*[contains(@*, "rfdLine")])=0]/*
```

When I test it in the chrome browser, it seems to work fine; however, when I try to scrape/parse using scrapy/python it goes through an infinite loop and the output file gets bigger and bigger.

What's wrong with it?

**UPDATE**

The desired output should be; tags must be kept:
Notice the footnotes are ignored.

```
<p class="rfdNormal0">Bunch of Text<span class="rfdFootnotenum"> (1) </span>Some Nested Text<span class="rfdFootnotenum"> (2) </span>Bunch of Text</p>
<p>Bunch of Text</p>
<p>Bunch of Text</p>
<p class="rfdNormal0">Bunch of Text</p>
<p>Bunch of text</p>
<p>Some Text here <span class="rfdAlaem">(</span><span class="rfdAie">Nested Text</span><span class="rfdAlaem">)</span> Bunch of Text</p>
```

Comment: Can you please post your desired output?

Comment: @IkramKhanNiazi I updated the question, showing the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The bug as I suspected was in the python/scrapy code and had nothing to do with the XPATH expression, hence why it went through the infinite loop.
Since I was looping through each page I had to put `.` to indicate that xpath expression is relative.

Thus my above expression:

```
//div[@class="pgcontent"]//*[contains(@*, "rfdLine")]/preceding-sibling::*|//div[@class="pgcontent" and count(.//*[contains(@*, "rfdLine")])=0]/*
```

becomes simply:

```
.//div[@class="pgcontent"]//*[contains(@*, "rfdLine")]/preceding-sibling::*|.//div[@class="pgcontent" and count(.//*[contains(@*, "rfdLine")])=0]/*
```